# CSS styles not being applied in XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I use XAMPP to create PHP pages and test them locally, but have an issue with the CSS styles not being applied.

When I browse to http://localhost/example/index.php  I get the correct PHP page output, but it is unstyled.

When I browse to file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/example/index.php  I get the page and it is styled so I know that my CSS links are not the problem.

Does anybody know what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Show you source/output code.

Comment: Show your CSS link(s).

Comment: you need to share code of css link

Answer (score 1):

since you didnt provide any code, I suspect you are using absolute path instead you should use relative path

suppose below is your structure

```
index.php
css
-- main.css
```

then you should link you css like

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

hope it helps